# Changing a buttons background image through using a random array

Tags: java, android, image, random

OK so I'm trying to get this button on its second click to display an image. I have 8 images for it to choose from and I want it to select it randomly. I set up an array with all of the `R.drawable.img` in the string and i tried placing it inside of this

```
   else if (click == 1)
                {
                    rpic = generator.nextInt(ppic);
                    spinntoke.setBackgroundResource(R.pic[rpic]);
                }
```

So it is not allowing me to do that. Any ideas as to how i can get the random generator to select 1 of those 8 pictures at random when it is clicked? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean you "set up an array with all of the R.drawable.img in the string...? R.pic[rpic] isn't a valid way to specify an image...You're not limiting your nextInt function to 8 numbers, even...not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not really provided enough info but here is what I imagine you would do.

have an array int[] that looks like this: [R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2, R.drawable.img3]

in onClick(): random = some random between 0 and array.size()-1;
spinntoke.setBackgroundResource(array[random]);

This way you have an array of ints (your R resources) where you can pick a random one. Don't forget to make your random generator only generate numbers from 0 to the array size-1.

Edit: code:

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
int random = randomGenerator.nextInt(array.size());
spinntoke.setBackgroundResource(array[random]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at drawableLeft property - or one of the others - rather than the background.