# I need to make this animation display as a button background

Tags: java, android, image, button

if anyone could help I would be really appreciative. Basically I want to get this animated GIF or whatever it needs, to be displayed as a button background. When I click the button I want it to change to this animation that shows a spinner spinning. Any idea how to get this animated GIF to work as a button background as a drawable?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918475/changing-a-buttons-background-image-through-using-a-random-array

Comment: Please, if the answers were useful to you, consider marking some answers as accepted in your other questions.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I would do it. First split the GIF and add each image to your drawable folder. Then add new xml file to your drawable (animation.xml).... see example below

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:oneshot="false">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/santa1" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/santa2" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/santa3" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/santa4" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/santa5" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/santa6" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/santa7" android:duration="200" />

</animation-list>
```

Then when you want it to start call it with this example below....

```
b_1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation);
                         AnimationDrawable b1Amin = (AnimationDrawable) b_1.getBackground();
                        b1Amin.start();
```